# Best way to iterate over objects of different types

Tags: typescript

I have an array that contains objects of different types. I learned from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types) that TypeScript can deduce union types such as `string | number` and `number | number[]` based on the code structure, but it can't seem to deal with more complex interfaces.

```
interface A {
    type: string;
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    type: string;
    b: string;
}

const a: A = { type: 'a', a: 'foo'};
const b: B = { type: 'b', b: 'bar'};

const arr = [a, b];

arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.type === 'a') {
        console.log(item.a); // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'A | B'.
    }
    else if (item.type === 'b') {
        console.log(item.b); // Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A | B'.
    }
});
```

What's the best practice in this case? Is it okay to just cast the item to the expected type in each block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible you just need to adjust your types a bit:

```
interface A {
    type: 'a';
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    type: 'b';
    b: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve that a little bit more, you can add to @Evert  solution the following:

```
enum Types{
a,
b}
interface A{
type:Types.a;
 a:string
}
interface B{
type:Types.b
b:string
}
```

This can be useful to avoid spelling mistakes.